# Want to concatenate graphic image with String

Tags: image, concatenation

I am facing an issue to concat image with String.
The reqmnt is when there is an error then on screen for eveery error message ther should be error icon prefixed with it.
Currently in xhtml(using jsf), its showing only one error icon:

I tried to achieve it using below code, but getting null prefixed before error message:

ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

message.append("
"+classLoader.getResource("/images/english/error12.gif")+ issue.getMessage()+"");

Your response awaited.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, in case any one else looking for it pls find below details:

Put your html tag as a string and then concat with whatever string you want to:

```
"<img src='/GroupeSetUpUiWar/javax.faces.resource/english/error12.gif.faces?ln=images' style='margin-right:5px;float:top;' />";
```